# How to change what modeline displays, based on major mode?

Tags: mode-line

i know i can change what info to display in modeline in `mode-line-format` variable. But how to display `mode-line-position` for one mode, but not display it for another?

Answer (score 1):

Use `(setq-local mode-line-position nil)` in the mode-hook.

Example:

```el
(define-derived-mode my-mode nil "my") ;; Our playground.

(defun remove-mode-line-position () ;; That's the thing you actually need.
  "Set `mode-line-position' buffer-locally to nil."
  (setq-local mode-line-position nil))

(add-hook 'my-mode-hook #'remove-mode-line-position) ;; Usage example.
```

If you create a new buffer with <kbd>C-x b</kbd> `*mybuf*` <kbd>RET</kbd> and call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `my-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> the position info in the modeline disappears for buffer `*mybuf*` but for no other buffer.